# PHP, Merge keys in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array which looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [DATA] => Array
    (
        VALUE1 = 1
        VALUE2 = 2
    )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (   
        [DATA] => Array
    (
        VALUE3 = 3
        VALUE4 = 4
    )
    )
)
```

And would like to turn it into this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [DATA] => Array
    (
        VALUE1 = 1
        VALUE2 = 2
        VALUE3 = 3
        VALUE4 = 4
    )
    )
)
```

I basically want to merge all the identical keys which are at the same level. 
What would be the best route to accomplish this?
Could the array_merge functions be of any use?

I Hope this makes any sort of sense and thanks in advance for any help i can get.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) to merge all the items in your original array together. And since that function takes a variable number of arguments, making it unwieldy when this number is unknown at compile time, you can use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) for extra convenience:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $array);
```

The result will have the "top level" of your input pruned off (logical, since you are merging multiple items into one) but will keep all of the remaining structure.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/shp1rk)**.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do this without a writing out a loop - very tidy!