# Merge multi array by keys

Tags: php, arrays

it's no easy explanation for me, but i try.
I have to create a multidimensional array merging the same array by keys,

My main array is:

```
[A] => Array
    (
        [A1] => 
        [A2] => 
        [A3] => 
        [A4] => 
        [A5] => 
    )
[A1] => Array
    (
        [A1a] => 
        [A1b] => 
        [A1c] => 
        [A1d] => 
        [A1f] => 
    )
[A1a] => Array
    (
        [A1a1] => 
        [A1a2] => 
        [A1a3] => 
        [A1a4] => 
        [A1a5] => 
    )
[A1a1] => value
```

So, what i need is:

```
[A] => Array
    (
    [A1] => Array
        (
        [A1a] => Array
            (
                [A1a1] => value
            )
        )
```

This is what i tried:

```
$final = array();
foreach($content as $key => $value){
    $final[$key] = glue($content, $key);
}

function glue($content, $i){
    $data = '';
    if(isset($content[$i])) {
        $data = $content[$i];
        if(is_array($data)){
            foreach($data as $cl => $value) {
                $data[$cl] = glue($content, $cl);
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;

}
```

With that i've got as i want but the end keys are empty:

```
[A14] => Array
(
    [A14a] => Array
        (
            [7461*] => 
        )

    [A14b] => Array
        (
            [A14b1] => Array
                (
                    [A14b11] => Array
                        (
                            [7600*] => 
                            [7601*] => 
                        )

                    [A14b12] => Array
                        (
                            [7602*] => 
                            [7603*] => 
                        )

                )
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: foreach($contents as $key => $value){
 $contents[$cl] = glue($contents, $cl);
}
 
function glue($contents, $i){
 $data = '';
  if(isset($contents[$i])) {
   $data = $contents[$i];
   if(is_array($data)){
    foreach($data as $cl => $value) {
     $data[$cl] = glue($contents, $cl);
    }
   }
  }
  
  return $data;
  
}
This add all the arrays into his "parent" but the end array is empty, loose the values,,,

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) merge items in array.
also if you google this

> php Merge multi array by keys
>   you will get result also this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214064/php-merge-keys-in-multidimensional-array).